# Full Address in XRLabel in Devexpress Winforms Reports?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

I Map full address in single **XRLable** (TextBox). If I preview the report, Address is adjust width  automatically to end of XRLabel, eg "**Trunk Road,**" it break into 2 words and second word "Road" displays in second line. How to solve this problem ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change XRLabel Property CanShrink and CanGrow to False to stop re sizing it on preview time.

Comment: No, My Label don't re sizing. I map one of my database column (Full Address) to this label. Address is long so it adjust automatically. Everything fine but problem is in my address street contain two words eg "First Main" in this case word "First" in line end and word "Main" in next line. So it is possible to adjust ? Till comma (,) in 1st line like that ?

Comment: In this case you have to use different labels for different lines. and with calculated fields expression you need to split with "Comma" and display result in respective label. but better then this I would recommended use richtext instead of label. If you want to split, multiple lines then I can help you with Devexpress Scripting in Scripting OnDataSourceDemanded you have to right logic to split it and assign text to respective label. by default, with Label Control your requirement cannot fulfill.

Comment: You can also try to setting MultiLine Property of Label to True
Try below link
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRLabel_Multilinetopic